# How do you send meta key over ssh on Mac?

Tags: emacs, ssh

I'm using ssh in Terminal to ssh into a Linux host where I'm running Emacs. I'd like to be able to use meta key commands, but I'm not how to send them from my (local) Mac to the (remote) Linux host. How do I do that?

Sorry if this isn't exactly a programming question.

Comment: You should ask the guys at superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Inside to the 3k+: I'm the one who misclicked meta. You may proceed to laugh at me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Well, you can either press Escape, then the key in question, or in the Terminal.app go to Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard and turn on "Use option as meta key".

On newer versions, it is under Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard.

Comment: Because I go back and forth between OS X and Linux (and their associated keyboards) I just use `C-[` all the time for Meta.

Comment: Hm. I found the setting you're talking about, but even after checking the box, I could not do meta commands in local or remote emacs. Also, APPLE-f would activate find in Terminal, not go forward one word in emacs. I've tried restarting Terminal, but that doesn't help either..

Comment: On Apple keyboards, the Option key is between the control and Apple (aka Command) keys on the left side.

Comment: @id thanks! I was thinking I should be using the apple key, not the option key. re using the option key instead of the apple key: Bleh! I wish there was a way to make the apple key work as the meta key!

Comment: @0x4b In System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> Modifer Keys you can swap Command and Option system-wide. I believe that ControllerMate will let you do that on a per-app basis. I have no affiliation. There may be other options as well.

Comment: Lifesaver! Thanks so much for this

Comment: The drawback of this is that you can no longer use Option to get special characters, which on many keyboards (such as the french keyboard) is a definitive no-no for programmers (you can't get `|` or  `\ ` for instance) :-( Using `ESC` (as a prefix rather than a composing key) is a more universal solution.